# Cannot read property 'construct' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

```
var Company;
(function (Company) {
    var companyApp = angular.module('company', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
    companyApp.constant('servicePath', Company.PathHelper.construct(''));
    companyApp.config(Company.HomeConfig);
    companyApp
        .controller('employeeController', Company.EmployeeController)
        .factory('employeeResource', Company.employeeFactory)
        .controller('departmentController', Company.DepartmentController)
        .factory('departmentResource', Company.departmentFactory);
})(Company || (Company = {}));
```

Can anyone please help me why i get next  error on line

```
companyApp.constant('servicePath', Company.PathHelper.construct(''));
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'construct' of undefined

My PathHelper:

```
  var Company;
(function (Company) {
    var PathHelper = (function () {
        function PathHelper() {
        }
        PathHelper.construct = function (virtualPath) {
            return location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + virtualPath;
        };
        return PathHelper;
    })();
    Company.PathHelper = PathHelper;
})(Company || (Company = {}));
```

Comment: It appears that your first code block (which references `Company.PathHelper` is getting called before your second code block (which initializes `Company.PathHelper`).

Comment: Thanks , but how can I fix this ? I have registered them in bundles , and how can i control which one is called first? 
  
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Application", ".js") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Configs", ".js") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Factories", ".js") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers", ".js") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Helpers", ".js") .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Models", ".js") );@JackA.

Comment: In that case, you should either update your question to include information about the bundling framework you are using, or ask a different question about how to ensure the order using your bundling framework.

Comment: Problem solved i put the                                                              bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/application")  at the end to load it after . It depends on the order you include the bunles .  Thanks anyway!@JackA.

Comment: if possible please paste full code of last version of you changes here